# Run Code Analysis and Suppress Active Issues (pragma tags)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, code-analysis, pragma

Visual Studio 2015 has this wonderful feature under the ANALYZE menu, called:

`Run Code Analysis and Suppress Active Issues`.

Being curious I ran that on my solution, and now I have auto-generated pragma tags all over the place. Is there any way to undo this? I prefer to be warned about hidden inheritance, unused fields and obsolete classes.

Is a "Find in Files" action (and manually deleting the lines) the only way to undo this feature?

Comment: Revert via source control?

Comment: I think the simplest thing would be to undo all the changes, using the system of version control. If you were fixing anything else in the code, then I think, it was a piece of bad luck.

To my mind, this function is too "impudent". For example, in PVS-Studio analyzer used an alternative way. The message markup is done in the external base. It can be committed to the version control system and all the messages will disappear, but the code will remain the same.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I have some uncommitted refactoring, so I'll just find and delete the 30-something lines in this case. Won't be running this command again, that's for sure :-)

Comment: I have the same problem. Is there not a definite answer to this?

Comment: The definitive answer is that you have to roll back your source control, or manually find/replace them all. Sorry I couldn't be of more help, but there is no undo button :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your setup you may have a few options available:

- Undo your changes from source control (Git, TFVC, SVN etc).
- Find-in-files, optionally using a regex and manually undo the changes.

The suppression in the source using `#pragma` allows Visual Studio to scope the suppression to the closest scope to prevent accidental suppression of the same type of issue in another place of the same method or class.

Answer (score 2):

If you realize immediately after executing the operation that you want to revert it, you can use Visual Studio's menu item

```
Edit >> Global Undo Suppress Diagnostics
```

to good effect.

Comment: I don't think this was an option in 2015